# How to make an ipad app only portrait?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, landscape-portrait

I am making an ipad app, and i set the the app to only portrait, but it still works in landscape? Why is this happening only on an ipad? How do i fix this?

Note: if the answer is in code, please write it in swift.

Comment: When you say you "set the app to only portrait," what did you do, exactly?

Comment: I went to the general tab, and unchecked landscape and portrait.

Comment: You unchecked them both?  Or you unchecked "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right", but checked "Portrait" and "Upside Down"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In xcode select your project. Go to Targets -> General, scroll down and you can select the Orientation as portrait only.

You can also make change to info.plist file to select proper orientations for Supported interface orientations (iPad)

Comment: I had to edit manually the plist flie, in the iPad section.

Answer (score 6):

[image]
In deployment Info section you can select your app orientation to support.