# One landscape view for whole app

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, landscape-portrait

How to setup just one landscape view for whole app? I want to show only one view (qrcode) when phone is rotated independently in wich view this happened. What is the easiest way to do it?

My app is in portrait and I want show users code when it rotated to landscape in whatever view this was done.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer. Just untick Portrait and tick on whatever Landscape orientation you want.

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/29791531/7198143](https://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Edit:

You should use Autolayout in your Storyboard to set up the right constraints so even in Landscape mode, the label for the code shows up. See this tutorial for more info.

[Autolayout tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)

Comment: No, you didn't understand, my app is in portrait and I want show users code when it rotated to landscape in whatever view this was done.